# In Silverlight, how can I get an animation from the template and use it through C# code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0

I have a control template that looks like as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="anchorButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="CommonGrid" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                <Image x:Name="CommonPic" Source="anchor.png" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Opacity="1"/> 
                <Image x:Name="CommonPicSelected" Source="anchorSelected.png" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Opacity="0"/> 
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonPic" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>    
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonPicSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                            
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

While in application, I can change the images when I mouseOver the button, but what I need to do is to set this through code (I'm calling a javascript, when I mouseOver the row, the respective point in my Silverlight app should be highlighted).

The link to javascript is already done:

```
 [ScriptableMember]
 public void UpdateText(int result)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         ButtonBase button = (ButtonBase)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(RegionCanvas, i);

         if (button.DataContext.ToString().Equals("" + result))
         {
             HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("highlightRow", button.DataContext);
         }
         else
         {
             HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("unHighlightRow", button.DataContext);
         }
    }
}
```

I wanted to use that animation set in the visual state and use inside the code shown above. Is that possible? How? If it is not, is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried googling? http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2007/06/01/call-scribtable-methods-from-javascript-with-silverlight.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: If you look the code above, I already have the scriptable member. The link between javascript and silverlight is already made. What I wanted was to link the xaml and the cs files, and to use the same storyboard I set in the mouseover event when the scriptable member is called. I already solved it other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to name the StoryBoard on XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="storyboard">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonPic" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonPicSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
```

And then you can call the Begin method from the code:

```
storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: How to call that to a specific object was my problem, but I already created my animation through the cs file directly.